# Iframe and html2canvas

Tags: javascript, iframe, jspdf, html2canvas

I have this javascript code of html2canvas and jsPDF to generate a pdf file from a screenshot. The only problem is that it doesn't show any information if there is an iframe inside the #newclass, i can't seem to figure out what am i doing wrong!

```
(function() {
    form = $('#newclass'),
        cache_width = form.width(),
        a4 = [595.28, 841.89]; // for a4 size paper width and height
    $('#create_pdf').on('click', function() {
        $('body').scrollTop(0);
        createPDF();
    });
    //create pdf
    function createPDF() {
        getCanvas().then(function(canvas) {
            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"),
                doc = new jsPDF({
                    unit: 'px',
                    format: 'a4'
                });
            doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20, 20);
            doc.save('techumber-html-to-pdf.pdf');
            form.width(cache_width);
        });
    }
    // create canvas object
    function getCanvas() {
        form.width((a4[0] * 1.33333) - 80).css('max-width', 'none');
        return html2canvas(form, {
            imageTimeout: 9000,
            removeContainer: true
        });
    }
}());
```

Comment: Which version of html2canvas? `5.0-something`, or lower?

Comment: @Siguza - 5.0-alpha2

Comment: I guess using a CORS proxy might make it work then... but I don't know of any html2canvas-supported hosted CORS proxies, and you'd have to edit the library to support `crossorigin.me` or `cors.io` or so...